# PostgreSQL: libpq functionality directly through the backend?

Tags: postgresql, libpq, postgresql-11, libpqxx

[libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq.html) is the C application programmer's interface to PostgreSQL. As I understand, this establishes multiple low-level connections to PostgreSQL's backend.

I was wondering, as a PostgreSQL backend developer, for example, a PostgreSQL extension developer (with PGXS), is there a similar interface or method available to execute an SQL query? In other words, I am no longer programming from my application, but I am programming from the PostgreSQL backend itself. I am guessing that this method would incur less overhead than libpq?

Comment: I think you are looking for [SPI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi.html)

Comment: yes, that's it. thanks